# What can i implement fmt lib

Tags: c++, format, lib, fmt

i try to insert fmt library to my project, but i don't really know what miss. if i complile it's everything ok, but when i want to use fmt::format function, i get errors...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9IE3.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwQFZ.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/myZlp.jpg
i make .lib file but again don't work

i try to make my own .lib file but dont't work. What i missed doing?

Comment: Try [vcpkg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vcpkg?view=vs-2019) to install fmt and other libraries.

Comment: i try with vcpkg and work, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the library to your project not just the include directory. Look at `Project Properties/Linker/General/Additional Library Directories` and `Project Properties/Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies`. You put the directory where the library is in the first one, and the name of the library (with .lib extension) in the second one

Comment: i try this but don't work

Comment: Well it's the right thing to do, you must have done something wrong.

Comment: yeah... i try to find solution, what i make wrong? what i forgot to implement?

Comment: You've done something wrong with your project settings. I have no idea what that is since I can't see what you have done. It could be something as simple as a spelling mistake, but I have no idea what obviously.